# How to get a value from powershell where the key has a dot at the beginning?

Tags: json, powershell

How do I get the value of a json where the key has "." at the beginning?

```
$json = '{".expires":"2022-10-13"}' | ConvertFrom-Json

cls
$json..expires #trying to get the value 2022-10-13
```

Error:

```
On the line:4 caractere:8
+ $json..expires
+        ~
You must provide a value expression after the '..' operator.
On the line:4 caractere:8
+ $json..expires
+        ~~~~~~~
Token 'expires' unexpected in the expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

The code above gives error if I put a colon, is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose the property name in quotes.

```
$json.".expires"
```